# sending payload to dialogflow from dialogflow android sdk

Tags: android, sdk, dialogflow-es, payload

I am using Android client of dialogflow - https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client

I would like to know how to send payload, lat, lon from my android application to dialogflow. some one could help on this?

**Update**

I am able to pass payload when I use the code like below,

```
final AIRequest aiRequest = new AIRequest();
AIOriginalRequest aiO = new AIOriginalRequest(); 
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
hm.put("element_1", "8888"); 
hm.put("element_2", "abcd"); 
aiO.setData(hm); 
aiRequest.setOriginalRequest(aiO); 
aiRequest.setQuery("find Cheese");
```

and I am getting this in server as below,

```
{
    "responseId": "ddsds-qwq-qwqwq-wqwqwq",
    "session": "<<session>>",
    "queryResult": {
        "languageCode": "en",
        "intentDetectionConfidence": "0.93",
        "allRequiredParamsPresent": "true",
        "parameters": {
            "item": "Cheese"
        },
        "fulfillmentMessages": [{
            "text": {
                "text": [""]
            }
        }],
        "queryText": "find Cheese",
        "intent": {
            "name": "<<session>>",
            "displayName": "item-req"
        }
    },
    "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
        "payload": {
            "element_2": "abcd",
            "element_1": "8888"
        }
    }
}
```

But as I am using AIService and using startListening method of that, I am not able to set the AIRequest and setOriginalRequest. There is no way to set OriginalRequest if are using AIService and startListening. The Dialogflow sdk is automatically doing this.

Any one faced such situation or solved this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to pass such information other than using system entities. You may need to do a hack if you can't find an entity to extract your data. In my project, I wanted to send a custom UUID. Now there was no specific system entity present in the Dialogflow which I could have used to extract the UUID so I used the simple approach of appending UUID to the Android response to Dialogflow and manually extracted it using || separator. 
You could do the following:

- Identify a system entity that can be used to detect lat, lon in the message to Dialogflow.
- Whatever the user response message is generated that you want to send to Dialogflow, programmatically append your lat, lon with it. Like `'Hi! My name is Abhinav Tyagi. 77.0000 28.0000'` would be my generated message.
- Train the Dialogflow Intent using this generated message and use the identified entity to extract the parameter in the webhook.
- If there is no entity, put the data in a JSON format.
- Append this JSON at the end of the user response message separated by a separator like || like `'Hi! My name is Abhinav Tyagi.||{"lon":"77.0000", "lat":"28.0000"}'` would be my generated message.
- Train the Dialogflow Intent using this generated message and variations.
- In the webhook, get the input query from the request, split it using the separator and then simply parse your JSON to extract the lat and lon.

Comment: Thanks Abhinav Tyagi for your answer.

Comment: Thanks Abhinav Tyagi for your answer.

I am using dialogflow android sdk aiService.startListening(); to initiate the conversation and not passing any query string or parameters. 

I saw some object like AIOriginalRequest and AIRequest. Can we use these objects to sending paylaod? 

Also there is an overloaded method for startListening with and RequestExtras, and the RequestExtras has a method to setAdditionalHeaders. Is there any way these can help us on this issue?

Comment: You may try, but in my case I was not successful. Whichever way it works you, please do post it. If my way worked accept the answer. If you find other answer, please post it.

Comment: I am able to pass payload when I use the code like below,

final AIRequest aiRequest = new AIRequest();
AIOriginalRequest aiO = new AIOriginalRequest();
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
hm.put("element_1", "8888");
hm.put("element_2", "abcd");
aiO.setData(hm);
aiRequest.setOriginalRequest(aiO);
aiRequest.setQuery("find Cheese");

Comment: and I am getting this in server as below,

{
 "responseId": "ddsds-qwq-qwqwq-wqwqwq",
 "session": "<<session>>",
 "queryResult": {
  "languageCode": "en",
  "intentDetectionConfidence": "0.93",
  "allRequiredParamsPresent": "true",
  "parameters": {
   "item": "Cheese"
  },
  "fulfillmentMessages": [{
   "text": {
    "text": [""]
   }
  }],
  "queryText": "find Cheese",
  "intent": {
   "name": "<<session>>",
   "displayName": "item-req"
  }
 },
 "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
  "payload": {
   "element_2": "abcd",
   "element_1": "8888"
  }
 }
}

Comment: But as I am using AIService and using startListening method of that, I am not able to set the AIRequest and setOriginalRequest.